# Confusion about Doob–Dynkin lemma

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Doob–Dynkin lemma: Let $X$,$Y$ $:\Omega \rightarrow R^n$ be random elements and $\sigma(X)$ be the $\sigma$ algebra generated by $X$. Then $Y$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable if and only if $Y=g(X)$ for some Borel measurable function $g:R^n\rightarrow R^n$.

Now I want to use this lemma to simplify $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}E[f(X_{n+1}) \vert \sigma(X_n)] 1_{\{N=n\}}$ where $N<\infty$ is any discrete stopping time and $f$ is a bounded measurable function. I know that by definition, conditional expectation $E[f(X_{n+1}) \vert \sigma(X_n)]$ is $\sigma(X_n)$-measurable. So, by applying Doob–Dynkin lemma, $E[f(X_{n+1}) \vert \sigma(X_n)]= g(X_n)$ and then,
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}E[f(X_{n+1}) \vert \sigma(X_n)] 1_{\{N=n\}}
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} g(X_n) 1_{\{N=n\}}   \hspace{5mm}(1)
\end{equation}

But I am not sure about the next step. I think it is wrong to substitute $n$ in $g(X_n)$ by $N$ because in that case, it means that $E[f(X_{N+1}) \vert \sigma(X_N)]= g(X_N)$ which doesn't seem correct to me because without fixing the value of $N$, the definition of $\sigma(X_N)$ is not clear to me. If we do this seemingly wrong substitution, then

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}E[f(X_{n+1}) \vert \sigma(X_n)] 1_{\{N=n\}}
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} g(X_n) 1_{\{N=n\}} =  g(X_N) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 1_{\{N=n\}} =  g(X_N).
$

But As I mentioned above, I think this substitution is wrong and (1) at the end should also depend on $N$. Am I right? Any idea for simplifying (1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to write $E[f(X_{n+1})|\sigma(X_n)] = g(n,X_n)$ to acknowledge that the function representing the conditional expectation depends on the joint distribution of $X_n$ and $X_{n+1}$ (as well as on the function $f$). With his fix, your computation shows that $E[f(X_{N+1})|\sigma(X_N)]=g(N,X_N)$, a.s. on $\{N<\infty\}$.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I didn't get why you said that $E[f(X_{n+1}) \vert \sigma(X_n)] = g(n,X_n)$. According to Doob–Dynkin lemma, it should depend only on $X_n$.

Comment: For example, $E[f(X_2)|\sigma(X_1)]$ is a measurable function of $X_1$ and $E[f(X_3)|\sigma(X_2)]$ is a measurable function of $X_2$, but it's not the same function in the two cases.

Comment: I know. But I mean why Doob–Dynkin lemma is not true here? By definition, conditional expectation $E[X\vert \mathcal{H}]$ is a  $\mathcal {H}$-measurable function and so the lemma should work. Am I wrong?

Comment: Oh, I got your point. You mean for each $n$, it is a function of $X_n$, but this function can be different for different $n$. So, indeed the function depends on $n$ as well. Thanks